# TouchableOpacity fire when scrolling

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

I am using FlatList for Scroll, I have a problem when I drag the screen using touch over a TouchableOpacity the onPress fires. Is there any way onPress is not fired when dragging the screen?

```
        cosnt renderItem=<TouchableOpacity onPress={this._onPress}>
            <View>
              <Text style={{ color: textColor }}>
               Test 
              </Text>
            </View>
         </TouchableOpacity>

         <FlatList
                data={props.places}
                renderItem={renderItem}
                keyExtractor={extractItemKey}
                onRefresh={props.getPlacesList}
                onEndReachedThreshold={0.5}
                onEndReached={getMorePlaces}
            />
```

Comment: Are you able to link code?

Comment: @PaulMcloughlin I added some code.

Comment: renderItem should be a function